# Android Activity Autorefresh/

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm pretty new to this, so sorry if my question might be trivial, and I'm sure this is basic stuff, but really I couldn't find a solution.

I'd like to realize an autorefresh in an active activity. I have a BT-service running in background and need a confirmation for some received data through mHandler. If it receives the expected I want to change the string of a textview, right now I'm using an extra button, but it's the ugliest way.
So I need a loop inside the activity, but what should I use? which action listener?

Answer (score 0):

ok what you can do is you can create a broadcast reciever in your activity. Write this code in you oncreate. fix it actually i am at home so you need to fix it i m giving you idea.

```
BroadcastReciever broadcast_obj = new BroadcastReciever (
                         @overrieded
                         onRecieve(Intent intent) {
                              String action = intent.getAction();
                              if(action == "my_bt_action") {
                                 //UPDATE YOUR TEXTVIEW AND DO WHATEVER WORK YOU WANT.
                               }
                           });


Now you need to register your broadcast for that just put these line in your oncreate after creating  Broadcast reciever which we have just done.

registerREciever(broadcast_obj, new IntentFilter("my_bt_action");

now you need to send your broadcast when your service will perform your calculation or your task for that it is simple.

Intent intent = new Intent (getApplictionContext,"my_bt_action");
sendBroadcast(intent);

from above code you can easily communicate between your activity and service.

hope it will work.
```

Comment: this seems right, i'll try it out later.
onReceive is the way :)

Comment: ya if it is correct then mark as answer so that other should not waste time on it and it will be helpful for other who are searching

Comment: i watched through again.
My activity is setting up the service, so they already communicating.

my activity starts, connects to a device, i'm sending something and wait for the answer, if the answer comes in it should refresh and show a changed textview

Comment: so just set text to text view. tv.settext(user_response_string)

Comment: tell me how you are recieving that text is changing or not.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try a loop inside a thread

```
    boolean update = false; // control the state to update textview
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        void run(){
            while(true){
                if(!update){
                   ...
                   textview.setText("something.");
                   ...
                   update = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: this wont work, because the textview is owned by the activity thread